# How can I disable 3 finger tap/swipe gestures available since iOS 13+ in my Flutter game?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, ipados

I have a Flutter game and it is not unlikely that a user puts 3 fingers on the screen. iOS 13.0 introduced three finger tap to open an edit menu and three finger swipe left/right to undo/redo. I want to disable this feature for the whole app.

What I learned from Google search results is that this can be controlled by the `editingInteractionConfiguration` property that many classes inherit from `UIResponder`.

In `UIResponder` it is defined like this:

```objectivec
@interface UIResponder : NSObject <UIResponderStandardEditActions>

// ...

// Productivity editing interaction support for undo/redo/cut/copy/paste gestures
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIEditingInteractionConfiguration editingInteractionConfiguration API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0));

@end

---

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public enum UIEditingInteractionConfiguration : Int, @unchecked Sendable {
    case none = 0
    case `default` = 1 // Default
}
```

I'm no Swift expert and my attempts to set this to none were adding the override below to my `AppDelegate` that inherits from `UIResponder` and overriding it in the `FlutterViewController` but it did not work:

```swift
// Class assigned in main storyboard view controller
class GameFlutterVC:FlutterViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("This gets printed.");
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    
    // Disable 3 finger tap gesture on iPad (not working)
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    override var editingInteractionConfiguration: UIEditingInteractionConfiguration { .none }
}
```

(using code from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-disable-undo-redo-copy-and-paste-gestures-using-editinginteractionconfiguration)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: All view controllers, views and a few other objects are responders. You just disabled it for one object. I’m thinking you need a base view controller where you override it and have everything else inherit from it.

Comment: Hi @cora, that is exactly what I try to do but I don't know where? I have a default Flutter app. iOS native code has a storyboard with just one view controller and an app delegate.